# Suddenly, none of my IndexedDB open request callbacks are invoked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I have had the same (working) code opening my various Indexeddb databases for the past 3 months.

Earlier this morning, they just stopped working. None of my callbacks from my `window.indexeddb.open()`request are ever called. And they used to!

```
request = window.indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);

request.onblocked = function(e) {
   console.log("onblocked");
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    console.log("onupgradeneeded");
};

request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log("onsuccess");
};

request.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("onerror");
};
```

I have tried different db versions, completely clearing my browser's IndexedDB data, Incognito browsers, just about everything I can think of. The same behavior happens every time - there are no errors in the console, the db is never opened and no callbacks are ever invoked.

Could this be a Chrome update that caused this? Has anyone else experienced this?

I found a similar issue, but it was back in 2012: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-html5/QvjsPbBdP4M/lK5UcnbkXhMJ

I am going a little bit crazy with this one and would appreciate any suggestions.

**Update**

This happens to be a Cordova/Ionic application and when the same code is loaded on an Android device, the databases open as expected, which tells me it is something very specific to my version of Chrome on my Mac: Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to completely uninstall Google Chrome from my computer. Once reinstalled, everything worked again. I haven't the slightest clue what weird, wonky state I managed to get my browser into, but completely starting over solved the problem. Hope this helps anyone else who many run into this.